# How to increase the resolution of the captured images in ARKit's face tracking?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, metal

I'm using [captureImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2867984-capturedimage) of `ARFrame` in `ARKit` to generate signatures for human faces and compare the similarities.  However, due to the poor resolution of the `captureImage`, the quality of the comparison is negatively affected compared to the `Vision` framework.
`capturedDepthData` shows that the resolution of the `capturedImage` in `ARKit` is only 640x480.

First, I've tried improving the video format to the highest resolution:

```swift
let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
if let videoFormat = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.supportedVideoFormats.sorted(by: { ($0.imageResolution.width * $0.imageResolution.height) < ($1.imageResolution.width * $1.imageResolution.height) }).last {
    configuration.videoFormat = videoFormat
}
```

But, this does not seem to improve the resolution of the `capturedImage`.

Second, I tried using [captureHighResolutionFrame](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/3975720-capturehighresolutionframe) and as well as change the video format:

```swift
if let videoFormat = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.recommendedVideoFormatForHighResolutionFrameCapturing {
    configuration.videoFormat = videoFormat
}
```

However, according to the documentation:

> The system delivers a high-resolution frame out-of-band, which means that it doesn't affect the other frames that the session receives at a regular interval

which seems to toggle back and forth between the regular `capturedImage` and the high resolution images, instead of replacing the regular images due to the asynchronous nature of capturing the high resolution images.  This is problematic because the size differences require `displayTransform` and `CGAffineTransform` to be used differently for scaling the images for each cases.

On top of that, the capturing of the images with this method creates the shutter sound at 60 times per second.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try this specific model but I hope it's doing good work since people are using it, and the transformer-based models achieved excellent scores in NLP.
Here is the link for one of them, specialized in enhancing image resolution
[model](https://huggingface.co/CompVis/ldm-super-resolution-4x-openimages). Hope this work well for your case.